# Youtube locking up Ubuntu after update

Tags: 10.04, youtube, lock

I am having locking issues on Youtube ever since today's update. Firefox and Google Chrome crash it. Changing back to kernel 6.****.28 (one below) did not help. Flash + Ubuntu is not really kicking. More info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10519150#post10519150).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it had some problems with intel graphic cards. I installed missing ATI card drivers, which had given me enough trouble on 9.04 that I decided to skip on 10.04, and now any further fault is on ATI's shoulder. At least youtube works now.